# Harman Air and IOS - Error ITMS 90034 again

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, air, adobe-animate

I'm looking for help to solve an **ITMS 90034** error: 
I can no longer install an application under development for testing, nor publish it on the AppStore.

- I downloaded the new `AppleWWWDRCAG3.cer` certificate.
- Re-applied for the authority certificate,
- Re-applied for the development and distribution certificates,
- Then re-applied for the mobileprovision files.

I imported all the above on my Windows PC.

When I compile a development version (last version of Animate and AIR), it works okay, but I can't install it (not signing with a submission Apple certificate).

When I compile a distribution version, it doesn't pass the transport validation, for the same reason. I have already compiled 17 applications on the AppStore, and now nothing works anymore.

Using: Adobe Animate 21.0.3 with  AIR 33.1.1.406 on Windows 10 last version.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue with x.406 right now. You can find more information [here.](https://github.com/Gamua/Adobe-Runtime-Support/issues/708)
Harman hasn't acknowledged it yet sadly.

Known Workarounds: Try using AIR SDK 33.1.1.345.